# Meteorjs and autoform simple schema - How to validate simple checkbox

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform

I'm using autoform and simple schema and I've defined a schema object with the following field:

```
confirm_nominee: {

type: Boolean,
autoform: {
  type: "select-checkbox-inline",
  options: function () {
    return [
      {
        label: "Check here to certify that the volunteer nominated in the application is not a current member of the organization’s Board of Directors.",
        value: 1
      }
    ];
  }
}
```

},

I just want it so if the box is left unchecked, the error reports "This field is required" and if it's checked, then the user is good to go.

This seems like it should be a really simple validation of whether the checkbox is checked or not.  I've tried adding in a defaultValue of 0, but that doesn't work either.

Any thoughts?

Thanks so much.

Comment: This should be the default action of simple schema: https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema#optional

Comment: actually... why are you using select-checkbox-inline for a single boolean value? You probably want to change it to boolean-checkbox OR change your type to [Boolean] if you have more than one option

Answer (score 1):

Set in your schema rules the key allowedValues: [true] and the checkbox must be checked to be true and pass validation

```
confirm_nominee: {

type: Boolean,
autoform: {
  type: "select-checkbox-inline",
  allowedValues: [true],
  options: function () {
    return [
      {
        label: "Check here to certify that the volunteer nominated in the application is not a current member of the organization’s Board of Directors.",
        value: 1
      }
    ];
  }
}
```